# getting data from JSON from facebook registration to netsuite

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, registration, netsuite

I have currently coded a registration page with facebook on one of my netsuite sites. The thing that I am having an issue with is, I do not know how to take the data from the registration page and have it be read onto another script and then sent over to the netsuite registration page.

Netsuite has not integrated facebook with their site yet, and we're limited to what we can do on there, which makes this problem a little scarce.

This is the third step to my problem and I should be solved. The issue is I need to know how I am to take the data from the JSON and have it sent to the netsuite registration script properly.

Netsuite is limited to JavaScript/ASP code I believe, so something done around JavaScript would be the most logical workaround.

Thanks

Comment: No, if you can use ASP code on the server-side, then that's the way to go - the answer you are getting from the registration plugin is best processed server-side.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail on your architecture and the problem you're trying to solve? You have a Facebook registration page in a NetSuite account (presumably a Suitelet, then)? Where exactly are you getting this JSON data from, and where does it need to be sent?

Comment: @egrubaugh360
http://www.flexibleindustrial.com/FI-Company-Info/register-with-facebook

here is the page I am working on.


I know I can upload an ASP file, I'm sure I am able to. I'm a PHP dev more but I can always read up how to do it.

What I am looking to do now, is once you click "register" it goes to a script that will read the data that was received and then the data will go to the official netsuite registration script.

As long as I can send the data and the user can register with netsuite, then we're got it made!.

Comment: ok, ASP doesn't work on netsuite, if I was to go to the link of the file, it would just download. I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

Netsuite uses Javascript on server-side. It has an extensive API that can be used to integrate any kind of third party service in Netsuite.

You can use nlapiRequestURL(http://suitecoder.appspot.com/static/api.html) to send/receive data from Facebook.

Also please clarify that what do you mean by **netsuite registration** . So that a more relevant answer can be given.

Comment: basically, the info I collect from the user's facebook I want to take it from the page and use it to register with our netsuite site without having to fill anything out.

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite supports inbound Single Sign On. It must be turned on in your account and there is some setup involved.